# Vertical-align of header with link in table

Tags: html, css

My code:

```
<table style="text-align: center; width: 100%;" border="2" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: middle; width: 33%;" bgcolor="#27ae60"><h2><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#34495e;">O mnie</a></h2>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: middle; width: 33%;" bgcolor="#27ae60"><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#34495e"><h2>Inne Produkty</h2></a>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: middle; width: 33%;" bgcolor="#27ae60"><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#34495e"><h2>Komentarze</h2></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Edit**: Original question has been interpreted as:

I want the text (link) of the first column to be in the middle, just as next two are but with having `<a href"#"...></a>` within `<h2>`. Because the place where I want to put it doesn't support doing it in the opposite way. Meaning, `h2` cannot be placed within `<a>` tags.

*OP wants the first link to be vertically aligned when having the `h2` tag within the `a` tag*

*(original text below)*

> I want the text(link) of first column to be in the middle, just as two next are but with havinh  within  cause place where I want to put it doesn't support doing it opposite way.

Comment: I respect that English probably isn't your first language, but I have no idea what you're asking for here. What is it you're trying to achieve that isn't working?

Comment: *"but with havinh within cause place where I want to put it doesn't support doing it opposite way."* huh?

Comment: Could you please describe more your problem, for example a little picture of desired result when you don´t want to explain it with text... I don´t understand to be a column with text link in the middle... in the middle of what concretely?

Comment: Aside from being invalid HTML, why can't your `h2` tag be placed in your `h2`? Are you getting errors? Are you trying to achieve something with JavaScript or CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I think now I understand what you want (thanks to Wes Foster):

Make your `h2` element an inline-block by adding the following `style` attribute to it: `<h2 style="inline-block;">`

```html
<table style="text-align: center; width: 100%;" border="2" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: middle; width: 33%;" bgcolor="#27ae60"><h2 style="inline-block;"><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#34495e;">O mnie</a></h2>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: middle; width: 33%;" bgcolor="#27ae60"><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#34495e"><h2>Inne Produkty</h2></a>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: middle; width: 33%;" bgcolor="#27ae60"><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#34495e"><h2>Komentarze</h2></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```